# What should be the Data Type in this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to use Name and ID in aspx control

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>'
```

I have a statement like below but I don't want to use object as Data Type in a global scope:

```
private object x = new {ID = 0, Name = "English"};
```

Should I create a new struct/class? Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the 2 values with a separator. So you don't need to create a separate class.

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") + "|" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")
```

And then split the value in code behind to get the values back

```
string[] itemArray = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|');

Label1.Text = itemArray[0];
Label2.Text = itemArray[1];
```